# Is it a good idea that using the race of multi-threads to be a random number generator?

Tags: multithreading, random

Due to the unpredictable of racing situation of multiple symmetric threads, is it good to use this uncertainty to build a **uniform** random generator?

For example, the codes from http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/mutex/call_once/ , call it twice to generate an random integer in [0,99].

```
#include <iostream>       // std::cout
#include <thread>         // std::thread, std::this_thread::sleep_for
#include <chrono>         // std::chrono::milliseconds
#include <mutex>          // std::call_once, std::once_flag
int winner;
void set_winner (int x) { winner = x; }
std::once_flag winner_flag;
void wait_1000ms (int id) {
// count to 1000, waiting 1ms between increments:
  for (int i=0; i<1000; ++i)
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1));
// claim to be the winner (only the first such call is executed):
  std::call_once (winner_flag,set_winner,id);
}
int main () {
  std::thread threads[10];
// spawn 10 threads:
  for (int i=0; i<10; ++i)
    threads[i] = std::thread(wait_1000ms,i+1);
  std::cout << "waiting for the first among 10 threads to count 1000 ms...\n";
  for (auto& th : threads) th.join();
  std::cout << "winner thread: " << winner << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

And call the code (from http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/alp-folder/alp-ch04-threads.pdf) certain times for a request length of random bits.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
/* Prints x’s to stderr. The parameter is unused. Does not return. */
void* print_xs (void* unused) {
  while (1) {
    sleep( 1);
    fputc ('x', stderr);
  }
  return NULL;
}
int main () {
  pthread_t thread_id;
/* Create a new thread. The new thread will run the print_xs function. */
  pthread_create (&thread_id, NULL, &print_xs, NULL);
/* Print o’s continuously to stderr. */
  while (1) {
    sleep( 1);
    fputc ('o', stderr);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Is that **real uniform** and with **no period**? The sequence is unable to reproduce, that may be a weak for debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with using thread timings as a random source (besides, say, the efficiency hit) is that you don't have any basis to believe that the values you'll get back will have any nice distribution. Thread schedulers usually try to be fair, which means that they'll try to give roughly equal time to each thread, modulated by some estimates of how much time each thread needs. The way this is done depends entirely on how the scheduler is implemented, and since the scheduler isn't optimizing over randomness, any randomness you get back should be treated as "kinda, but not very" random. If this does end up being uniformly random, it would purely be by coincidence and would almost certainly not be portable. Worse, it wouldn't be *provably* uniformly-random, so you'd have no reason to trust that what you're doing works, and consequently no one else would have a reason to trust that what you're doing works.

I'm not sure if this is a purely hypothetical question or not. If you are actually thinking about doing this, you should probably stop and ask why you'd want to do this. If you need just a "good enough" random source, use the library default. If you need something cryptographically secure, use `/dev/random` to get the best random bytes you can, and if that's not enough bytes, feed it to a cryptographically secure hash function in a way that's justified by best practices.

Now, that said, many OSes do use thread timing information as input to their entropy accumulators, which then are used later on to get high quality random bits. This works because these values are mixed with other seemingly unpredictable events (network data, capacitor discharges, screen contents, CPU temperatures, clock time, etc.) in a way that combines the entropy of each into a single high-entropy source. If you'd like to use information like this for randomness, just go about it in the normal way by either reading `/dev/random` or using another OS-specific mechanism to get the high-entropy bytes.